# JSON Path Autocomplete in VS Code using JSONSchema

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema

In VS Code, there are several tags which trigger autocompletion and validation for local file path references. For example, when entering an img tag:

[image: Path autocomplete]

I have a json file which stores the metadata for an image grid, and I'd like to try to add a validation that the image path is typed in correctly. For example, here's an a json file that contains items with image paths and other metadata:

<sub>**images.json**</sub>

```js
[
    {
        "color": "red",
        "path": "./images/kitten.jpeg" /* identify value type as local path */
    },
    /* ... more items ...*/
]
```

And here's a [JSON Schema Definition](http://json-schema.org/draft-04/json-schema-core.html) which has been [applied to the vs workplace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings):

<sub>**.vscode/settings.json**</sub>

```js
{
    "json.schemas": [
        {
            "fileMatch": [
                "/images.json"
            ],
            "schema": {
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
                "type": "array",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "color": {"type": "string", "enum": ["blue", "red", "green"]},
                      "path":  {"type": "string", /* what to put here */},
                    }
                  },
                ]
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to check local file paths using [JSON Schema Validation](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html) or some alternative way to tell VS Code that a particular field is representing local file references?

Comment: You can use a `uri` format, but it will still validate non-file-paths (if the validator VSCode uses supports formats at all).  I think the main problem you're going to face is that file paths vary based on the system you're running.